# Calculo con $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Cordial saludo a todos, tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando basarme en un codigo que funciona correctamente que es el siguiente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> mi aplicacion </title>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="miAplication" ng-controller="miControlador">
  <p>Nombre de empleado:<input type="text" ng-model="empleado.nombreEmp"></p>
  <p>Horas trabajadas:<input type="number" ng-model="empleado.horasTrab"></p>
  <p>Cuota por hora: <input type="number" ng-model="empleado.cuotaHora"></p>
  <p>El sueldo de {{empleado.nombreEmp}} es de {{obtenerSueldo()}} </p>
 </div>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var app =angular.module('miAplication',[]);
  app.controller('miControlador',function($scope){
   $scope.empleado={
    nombreEmp:"Luis Camilo Jimenez",
    horasTrab:45,
    cuotaHora:10000,
    sueldo:0
   }
   $scope.calcularSueldo=function(){
    $scope.empleado.sueldo=$scope.empleado.horasTrab*$scope.empleado.cuotaHora;
   }
   $scope.obtenerSueldo=function(){
    $scope.calcularSueldo();
    return $scope.empleado.sueldo;
   }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en mi codigo al tratar de hacer la operacion de la multiplicación en el $scope no me muestra nada y tampoco al ejecutar me muestra los valores sugeridos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Guia 2. actividad 2.2.</title>
 <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
     <style>
        table, th , td  {
          border: 1px solid grey;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #ffffff;
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app= "convertirGradosC" ng-app = "micontrolador">
  <p>Ingrese GradosC fahrenheit inicial:<input type="number" ng-model="GradosC.Inicialf"></p>
  <p>Ingrese GradosC fahrenheit final:<input type="number" ng-model="GradosC.Finalf"></p>
  <p>{{GradosC.Inicialf}} °F son {{obtenerCelcius()}} °C</p>
  <p>{{obtenerCelcius()}}</p>

  <table>
     <thead>
        <td><b> GradosC Fahrenheit </b></td><td><b> GradosC Celcius </b></td>
     </thead>
     <tr>
      <td>{{GradosC.Inicialf}}</td>
       <td>{{GradosC.Finalf}}</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var app =angular.module('convertirGradosC',[]);
  app.controller('micontrolador',function($scope){
   $scope.GradosC={
    Inicialf:10,
    Finalf:20,
    Celcius:0
   }
   $scope.calcularCelcius=function(){
    $scope.GradosC.Celcius=($scope.GradosC.Inicialf-32)*(5/9);
   }
   $scope.obtenerCelcius=function(){
    $scope.calcularCelcius();
    return $scope.GradosC.Celcius;
   }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota.Lo que sale como tabla lo coloque para verificarf que si me mostrara otro valor distinto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

pude terminar mi codigo que permite leer el valor inicial y el valor final en grados Fahrenheit; e imprime una tabla con equivalencias en grados Celsius, desde el valor inicial hasta el valor final de 1 en 1.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <title> Guia 2. actividad 2.2.</title>
    <style>
        table, th , td  {
          border: 1px solid grey;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #ffffff;
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app= "convertircentigrados" ng-controller = "micontrolador">
  <p>Ingrese Grados fahrenheit inicial:<input type="number" ng-model="centigrados.inicialf"></p>
  <p>Ingrese Grados fahrenheit final:<input type="number" ng-model="centigrados.finalf"></p>

  <h2>Tabla de equivalencias entre Grados Fahrenheit y Grados Centigrados</h2>

  <table>
     <thead>
      <th><b>Index</b></th>
      <th><b>Grados Fahrenheit</b></th>
        <th><b>Grados Celcius</b></th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat= "i in range | limitTo:(centigrados.finalf-centigrados.inicialf+1)+i">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td>{{centigrados.inicialf++i}}</td>
        <td>{{(centigrados.inicialf+i-32)*(5/9)|number: 1}}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  var app =angular.module('convertircentigrados',[]);
  //controlador
  app.controller('micontrolador',function($scope,){
   $scope.centigrados={
    inicialf:0,
    finalf:100,
   }
   var range=[];
   for (var i = $scope.centigrados.inicialf; i < $scope.centigrados.finalf; i++) {
    range.push(i)
   }
   $scope.range= range;
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

encontre el error más grande por el cual no me calculaba lo que yo necesitaba.

se encuentra en la siguiente linea.

```
<div ng-app= "convertirGradosC" ng-app = "micontrolador">
```

El problema era que no estaba llamando la directiva `Controller`si no `ng-app`.

gracias a todos, cuando temrmine el codigo lo posteare como respuesta.